# Transform jRuby code in Ruby code

Tags: ruby, jruby, rjb

i have this code:

```
require 'java'
require 'iText-5.0.6.jar'

module Pdf
  include_package "com.itextpdf.text.pdf"
  include_package "java.io"

  def self.write
    reader = PdfReader.new('application.pdf');
    stamper = PdfStamper.new(reader, FileOutputStream.new('completed.pdf'))
    form = stamper.acro_fields
    puts "Form has these fields: #{form.fields.key_set.to_a}"
    form.set_field("some_zipcode_field", "94115")
    stamper.close
  end
end

Pdf.write
```

in `jRuby` and i want to translate to `Ruby`, using `rjb`

anyone nows how can i do that?

Comment: for those that still don`t understand... i can`t use jruby on production, that`s why i need RJB to use jruby code. but i don`t now how to do that...

Comment: What are the barriers to getting jruby in production? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use libraries like iText from regular Ruby via "RJB", the Ruby-Java bridge. I do not know the proper sequence of calls in RJB to make that happen, but it is possible and I know of folks doing it.

An alternative would be to use the pure-Ruby "prawn" library, which would work the same on both JRuby and Ruby

Comment: i`ve tried prawn at first, but prawn doesn`t allow me to create a pdf from a template, that`s why i`m using iText

Comment: And besides I want to fill a PDF form, which, using prawn I did not found any way of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Java library like iText then you can't. You'll need to modify the code to use a different PDF library in order for it to work in C Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the rjb site will help with more specifics [RJB](http://rjb.rubyforge.org/).  Unfortunately, I don't think it covers all of its features.

I don't think you can load whole packages in RJB, but since you are only using a handful of classes you can do individual imports:

JString = Rjb::import('java.lang.String')

I also think Rjb does not have all the shortcut aliases for Java methods so you may end up needing to setField instead of set_field or field=.  I am not an Rjb user, but I would really like to collaborate with Rjb to make our two syntaxes more compatible. [note: You might want to challenge this advice when you get Rjb set up...I just have never seen an example with the shortcuts in them]